# Add opening balance to the first closing balance row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table where I display debit, credit and balance in my table. I have loaded the following definition, sample data and code into [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/303f2/1):

```
CREATE TABLE chequebook (
  entry_date timestamp default now() PRIMARY KEY,
  entry_item varchar(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  entry_amount decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO chequebook (entry_date,entry_item,entry_amount) VALUES 
('2010-01-02 12:34:00','Deposit A',215.56),
('2010-01-02 21:44:00','Withdrawal A' ,-23.34),
('2010-01-03 10:44:00','Withdrawal B',-150.15),
('2010-01-03 15:44:00','Deposit B',154.67),
('2010-01-04 18:44:00','Withdrawal C',-65.09),
('2010-01-05 08:44:00','Withdrawal D',-74.23),
('2010-01-06 14:44:00','Deposit C',325.12),
('2010-01-06 20:44:00','Withdrawal E',-80.12),
('2010-01-07 04:44:00','Withdrawal F',-110.34),
('2010-01-07 16:44:00','Withdrawal G',-150.25),
('2010-01-08 16:44:00','Withdrawal H',-23.90),
('2010-01-08 21:44:00','Withdrawal I',-75.66),
('2010-01-08 22:44:00','Deposit C',275.78),
('2010-01-09 11:44:00','Withdrawal K',-85.99),
('2010-01-09 21:44:00','Withdrawal J',-100.00); 

set @depos=0;
set @total=0;
select 
  entry_date, 
  entry_item, 
  entry_amount, 
  if( entry_amount>0, @depos:=entry_amount, @depos:=@depos+entry_amount ) as depos_bal,
  @total:=@total+entry_amount as net_bal
from chequebook
order by entry_date;
```

I am facing issues when I want to add an opening balance to the `net_bal` column from the PHP MYSQL query.

I am facing issues in adding the Opening Balance to the very FIRST COLUMN and there after it should minus or plus from the desired fields.

For example:

```
|                entry_date |   entry_item | entry_amount | depos_bal | net_bal |
|---------------------------|--------------|--------------|-----------|---------|
| January, 02 2010 12:34:00 |    Deposit A |       215.56 |   5215.56 | 5215.56 | <--- 5000 is openingbalance
| January, 02 2010 21:44:00 | Withdrawal A |       -23.34 |   5192.22 | 5192.22 |
| January, 03 2010 10:44:00 | Withdrawal B |      -150.15 |   5042.07 | 5042.07 |
```

Opening Balance is fetched from different table.

How can I finish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the initial local @Total variable to your initial balance. From your SQLFiddle:

```
set @depos=0;
set @total=5000;
select 
  entry_date, 
  entry_item, 
  entry_amount, 
  if( entry_amount>0, @depos:=entry_amount, @depos:=@depos+entry_amount ) as depos_bal,
  @total:=@total+entry_amount as net_bal from chequebook
order by entry_date;
```

If it's coming from a different query, set the variable that way.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks so much! I don't understand why didn't I think of that. I was trying to do with the query. Never guessed it on your solution. Thanks again.